# getting null JSONObject values

Tags: java, android, json, null

I'm trying to create a JSONObject as code below. But Android Studio is saying that it's null. Where is my mistake?

I tried two different ways to create it.

1st

```
String JSONString = "{" +
            "  \"retorno\": {" +
            "    \"empresas\": [" +
            "      {" +
            "        \"cnpj\": \"05.743.645/0001-38\"," +
            "        \"razao_social\": \"GISELA TRANSPORTES E DISTRIBUIDORA DE FLORES LTDA - ME\"," +
            "        \"endereco\": \"EST RSC-453 (ROTA DO SOL) KM 93,8\"," +
            "        \"bairro\": \"BAIRRO ALFANDEGA\"," +
            "        \"numero\": 26," +
            "        \"complemento\": \"\"," +
            "        \"telefone\": \"3462 2749\"," +
            "        \"celular\": \"\"," +
            "        \"email\": \"giselaflores@giselaflores.com.br\"" +
            "      }" +
            "    ]" +
            "  }" +
            "}";
try {
        JSONObject jsonEmpresa = new JSONObject(JSONString);
        String email = jsonEmpresa.getString("email");
} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

2nd

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonEmpresa = new JSONObject();
        jsonEmpresa.put("cnpj", "05.743.645/0001-38");
        jsonEmpresa.put("razao_social", "GISELA TRANSPORTES E DISTRIBUIDORA DE FLORES LTDA - ME");
        jsonEmpresa.put("endereco", "EST RSC-453 (ROTA DO SOL) KM 93,8");
        jsonEmpresa.put("bairro", "BAIRRO ALFANDEGA");
        jsonEmpresa.put("numero", 26);
        jsonEmpresa.put("complemento", "");
        jsonEmpresa.put("telefone", "3462 2749");
        jsonEmpresa.put("celular", "");
        jsonEmpresa.put("email", "giselaflores@giselaflores.com.br");

        String email = jsonEmpresa.getString("email");
} catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

String email's value is *null*, it should be *giselaflores@giselaflores.com.br*.

When I tried to debug, I had the message *jsonEmpresa: "null"*.

Comment: **where** is it null? You've not shown the code after the variable is made. Did you look at the logcat for the parse exception?

Comment: By the way, you're building two different objects here, so can you please show a [mcve]?

Comment: `String email = jsonEmpresa.getString("email");` email: null jsonEmpresa: "null"

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full code. And your object isn't null. It's the values within it

Comment: For the first block, no there is no email key in your object. You must get `retorno`, then `empresas` first... For your second example, that should return a result for the email key

Comment: @cricket_007 I agree with you, but it's returning null.

Comment: Again, where are you displaying the email? Please show a [mcve] of all related code... Or please add a Log.d line immediately after you get the email variable and show us your logcat output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get email value for given example, you should to do like

```
 String JSONString = "{" +
                "  \"retorno\": {" +
                "    \"empresas\": [" +
                "      {" +
                "        \"cnpj\": \"05.743.645/0001-38\"," +
                "        \"razao_social\": \"GISELA TRANSPORTES E DISTRIBUIDORA DE FLORES LTDA - ME\"," +
                "        \"endereco\": \"EST RSC-453 (ROTA DO SOL) KM 93,8\"," +
                "        \"bairro\": \"BAIRRO ALFANDEGA\"," +
                "        \"numero\": 26," +
                "        \"complemento\": \"\"," +
                "        \"telefone\": \"3462 2749\"," +
                "        \"celular\": \"\"," +
                "        \"email\": \"giselaflores@giselaflores.com.br\"" +
                "      }" +
                "    ]" +
                "  }" +
                "}";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonEmpresa = new JSONObject(JSONString);
            JSONObject retorno = jsonEmpresa.getJSONObject("retorno");
            JSONArray empresas = retorno.getJSONArray("empresas");
            JSONObject empresa =  empresas.getJSONObject(0);

            String email =empresa.getString("email");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: I got _java.lang.NullPointerException_ at line `JSONArray empresas = retorno.getJSONArray("empresas");`

Comment: _jsonEmpresa_ and _retorno_ are both null.

Comment: @LucasPostingher you should run it on under androidTest folder, If you run it on test side it will throw not mocked exception